# Nested Multicols in a Table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to recreate a nested table like this with multicols.

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

My best guess is the following, however, it doesn't work

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Ethnic Partitioning and Civil Conflict: Baseline Country Fixed Effects Estimates} 
  \label{} 
   \resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccc} 
%\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All ethnicity-country homelands} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Ethnicity-country homelands close
to the national border} & \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{All observations} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Excl. Capitals} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{All observations} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Excl. Capitals} & \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
SPLIT (partitioning) & 0.0380 & 0.0480$^{*}$ & 0.0456 & 0.0321 & 0.0142 & $-$0.0132 & $-$0.0031 & $-$0.0203 \\ 
& (0.0268) & (0.0245) & (0.0298) & (0.0318) & (0.0407) & (0.0466) & (0.0441) & (0.0461) \\ 
& & & & & & & & \\ 
SPILL (adjacent split) & 0.0445 & 0.0910$^{**}$ & 0.0867$^{**}$ & 0.0787$^{*}$ & 0.0776 & 0.0834$^{*}$ & 0.1121$^{**}$ & 0.0958$^{*}$ \\ 
& (0.0498) & (0.0369) & (0.0395) & (0.0433) & (0.0575) & (0.0493) & (0.0485) & (0.0532) \\ 
& & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Simple controls & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Location controls & No & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Geographic controls & No & No & Yes & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes \\ 
Country fixed Efffects & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Observations & 1,238 & 1,238 & 1,238 & 1,156 & 619 & 619 & 619 & 572 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.2762 & 0.3733 & 0.3801 & 0.3767 & 0.2550 & 0.3747 & 0.3841 & 0.3838 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Note....} \\ 
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Replace the `&` before the `\cmidrule` commands with `\\ `. Also, do not use `resizebox` on a table as this will only lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works well. I am getting a slightly larger spacing between column 7 and 8. What would you suggest instead of resizebox?

I am using the following document class `documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}` in case this is important

Comment: In order to make sure your table fits into the available space, you could reduce the font size to `\small` or `\footnotesize`, adjust the value of `\tabcolsep` and introduce line breaks in the lengthy column header texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the screenshot you posted looks like it may have been created with a `tabularx` environment, which allows automatic line-breaking inside cells.

Whatever else you do, *I implore you* to get rid of the wretched `\resizebox` approach, which more or less *guarantees* that the table will be well-nigh unreadable. Instead, place the table in landscape mode using, say, the `sidewaystable` environment that's provided by the `rotating` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman text and math font
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}} % bottom-alignment of cell contents
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep\relax}Y} % to span 4 'Y' columns

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape mode
\caption{Ethnic partitioning and civil conflict: 
         Baseline country fixed effects estimates\strut} 
\label{tab:partitioning} 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{Y} @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{Z}{All ethnicity-country homelands} 
& \multicolumn{4}{Z@{}}{Ethnicity-country homelands close to the national border}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{All observations} & Excl. capitals 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{All observations} & Excl. capitals \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8} \cmidrule(l){9-9} 
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\itshape Panel A\@. Negative binomial ML estimates}\\ 
\addlinespace
SPLIT (partitioning) & 0.0380 & 0.0480$^{*}$ & 0.0456 & 0.0321 & 0.0142 & $-$0.0132 & $-$0.0031 & $-$0.0203 \\ 
& (0.0268) & (0.0245) & (0.0298) & (0.0318) & (0.0407) & (0.0466) & (0.0441) & (0.0461) \\ 
\addlinespace
SPIL (adjacent split) & 0.0445 & 0.0910$^{**}$ & 0.0867$^{**}$ & 0.0787$^{*}$ & 0.0776 & 0.0834$^{*}$ & 0.1121$^{**}$ & 0.0958$^{*}$ \\ 
& (0.0498) & (0.0369) & (0.0395) & (0.0433) & (0.0575) & (0.0493) & (0.0485) & (0.0532) \\ 
\midrule
Simple controls & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Location controls & No & No & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Geographic controls & No & No & Yes & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes \\ 
Country fixed effects & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
Observations & 1,238 & 1,238 & 1,238 & 1,156 & 619 & 619 & 619 & 572 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.2762 & 0.3733 & 0.3801 & 0.3767 & 0.2550 & 0.3747 & 0.3841 & 0.3838 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip % no need to put the notes inside the tabularx env.
Notes: \dots
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```